# DES decryption error "Bad Data" in C# when closing cryptostream

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, des

I try to decrypt an  encrypted byte array (encrypt with K1 and decrypt with K2). Visual Studio throws an exception "BAD DATA" when it tries to close my crypto stream

here's my code snippet of DES decryption

```
public Byte[] Decrypt(Byte[] cipherData, Byte[] key, Byte[] iv)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DES mDES = DES.Create();
        mDES.Key = key;
        mDES.IV = iv;
        mDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, mDES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length);
        cs.Close();
        Byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

the initial vector is the same as encryption. I don't know why this error occurred.

***Added:***
As recommended by Greg B, I post here my code snippet of encryption. The output of encryption is the input of decryption (two different keys)

```
        public Byte[] Decrypt(Byte[] cipherData, Byte[] key, Byte[] iv)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DES mDES = DES.Create();
        mDES.Key = key;
        mDES.IV = iv;
        mDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, mDES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length);
        cs.Close();
        Byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

Comment: If it's throwing an exception when decrypting, maybe there is something wrong with your encryption routine. Might be worth posting that code too...

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591361/c-bad-data-exception-when-decrypting-encrypted-file

Comment: I had a look at the link suggested by Alireze but it seems to me that it doesn't resolve my problem :(

Comment: use FlushFinalBlock() in your encryption method, before the close.

Comment: @Marvin Smit: I tried your suggestion but the error still persists...

Comment: Although this thread is about 3DES instead of single DES encryption, I think the same issue is the cause of your problems. Maybe this link will provide more info?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512348/bad-data-when-encrypt-and-decrypt-with-tdes

ps; Both code segements show the decrypt, can you update one to show the encrypt method?

Comment: You realise you've posted the decryption routine twice?

Answer (score 3):

the problem you encountered comes from the selected padding mode.

since padding is used when decrypting your cipher text the cryptostream tries to remove the padding when your retrieve the decrypted bytes. since you don't use the key the data was encrypted with, you will get "garbage" ... the cryptostream fails to detect the padding that needs to be removed, and the operation fails with the observed exception.

if you want to rebuld someething like 3DES with the DES class use PaddingMode NONE for your decryption and the following encryption step (so only the first encryption or the last decryption uses padding)